# Building an iPhone app exported from Expo using Fastlane (or any other method)

Tags: build, fastlane, expo

I have an iPhone app that I am exporting from Expo, so I can build using my own hardware.

Simply put I call `exp detach` then I call

```
cert
sigh
gym
```

using `fastlane beta`

This fails to build as it cannot sign my application. The error is

```
[15:27:30]: ▸ === BUILD TARGET appname OF PROJECT appname WITH CONFIGURATION Release ===
[15:27:30]: ▸ Check dependencies
[15:27:30]: ▸ No profiles for 'com.getexponent.appname' were found:  Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching 'com.getexponent.appname'.
[15:27:30]: ▸ Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.3'
```

Clearly it is picking up the `com.getexponent.` from somewhere. I have the correct bundle name set in `app.json`.

I have also updated my `Fastfile`

```
lane :beta do    
    update_app_identifier(
      xcodeproj: '../ios/appname.xcodeproj',
      plist_path:'./appname/Supporting/Info.plist',
      app_identifier: "com.mycompany.appname"
    )  
    cert
    sigh
    gym( 
      scheme: "appname",
      workspace: '../ios/appname.xcworkspace'
      )
  end
```

however I get the same error message.

Is there something in Expo detach I can alter, or what do I need to change in `fastlane`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've opened an issue about that on the Expo repository [here](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/414). It seems that the `exp detach` command is not really deployment-friendly...

I am using [Bitrise](https://www.bitrise.io/) for my deployment, and it includes a step to modify the `PROJECT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER`. You can do the following:

```
NEW_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER="com.mynewbundle.identifier
PBXPROJ_FILE="path/to/project.pbxproj"

sed -i "" "s/\(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = \).*\(;\)/\1${NEW_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}\2/" $PBXPROJ_FILE
```

(based on [this Bitrise step](https://github.com/emenegro/bitrise-step-product-bundle-identifier/blob/master/step.sh#L31)).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I added this to the start of my `Fastfile` step

```
sh "sed -i '' 's/com.getexponent.allotmentlab/com.foam.allotmentlab/g' '../../ios/allotmentlab.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'"
```

This is a bad solution because you have to know what the wrong string is. You also need to know the route from the `Fastfile` to the `project.pbxproj`. But it's the best fix I could come up with.